# "Error loading data from server: Server error." - help on configuring VisualEditor and Parsoid extensions for MediaWiki on localhost?

Tags: apache-http-server, mediawiki, runtime-error

I've been having issues with Parsoid and VisualEditor recently, getting this error everytime I try to edit the page:

> Error loading data from server: Server error.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to edit my config to setup appropriately. In the Parsoid `localSettings.js`, the first value should be an identified for a wiki, and the second a URL to the `api.php` service.

```
parsoidConfig.setInterwiki( 'localhost', 'http://127.0.0.1/api.php' );
```

Secondly, I had to change `$wgVisualEditorParsoidURL` in `LocalSettings.php` to reflect this:

```
$wgVisualEditorParsoidURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/localhost';
```